# problem with cards shuffle function on button click js

Tags: javascript

[image]I tried to shuffle array of cards
it doesnt work I dont know why

```
function shuffle(array) {
let curr = array.length, rand;

while (curr != 0) {
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * curr);
    curr--;
    [array[curr], array[rand]] = [array[rand], array[curr]];
}

return array;
```

}

```
 const shuffleButton = document.querySelector(".shuffleButton");
shuffleButton.onclick = shuffle(cards);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that you're calling the `shuffle` function directly in the click event handler for the `shuffleButton`, rather than passing in a function reference. This means that the shuffle function is executed immediately when the page is loaded, rather than waiting for the button to be clicked.

To fix this, you can wrap the call to `shuffle` inside an anonymous function that gets executed when the button is clicked, like this:

```
const shuffleButton = document.querySelector(".shuffleButton");
shuffleButton.onclick = function() {
  shuffle(cards);
};
```

This will ensure that the shuffle function is only executed when the button is clicked.

Also, make sure that the cards array is defined and contains the cards you want to shuffle.

It's possible that the click event is not being registered for the button element. You can try using the addEventListener() method instead of assigning the onclick property, like this:

```
const shuffleButton = document.querySelector(".shuffleButton");
shuffleButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  shuffle(cards);
});
```

Comment: thanks , but it doesnt work either
I updated to code I have